# jquery mobile dialogs, passing values between pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to make a popup ([page dialogs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html)) in jquery mobile with some input fields. How would i pass data from the popup to my main page?

And does the popup need to be a complete jquery ui page ([page anatomy](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html)), or just a

```
<div data-role="page"> 
...
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't dug too far into jQuery mobile, but at a quick glance, it doesn't look much different than the popup dialogs from jQuery UI. In which case, you can try binding a data collector to a button in the initiation of the dialog.

```
$('#testdiv').dialog({ //initiate dialog
  someoption: "test", //fake stuff for example
  otheroption: "foo", // ---
  buttons: {  //define buttons for dialog
    "Ok": function() { //define "ok" button
      var userInput = $('#inputInDialog').val(); //get value of the textbox in the dialog
      $('#domOnMainPage').text(userInput); //write that value to main page
    }
  }
})
```

Again, I haven't got into mobile, but this is probably going to be pretty close to what you're looking for, I'm thinking.

Comment: Looking further into the documentation, I'm seeing some info that may conflict with my answer, and some that supports it. jQuery Mobile seems to do a lot of inline functions, but also mentions you can close a dialog programatically using $('#testdiv').dialog('close'). So I think there may be multiple ways to handle a dialog in JQmobile. I'll read up some more

Comment: Thanks for your time Kyle, ill accept this. Where did you find the .dialog method btw?

Comment: I knew it from jQuery UI, but I saw it in your first link, http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html under closing dialogs, and it made me think the structure might be the same

Answer (score 7):

Mobile page communication(passing data between pages) can be done in following ways:

1. sessionStorage or localStorage of HTML5 Dom storage.
2. global variables.
3. jQuery.data()

Example for the usage of Jquery.data() is referred below.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49735179/dialog-data-transfer.html.

Hope this may help you :)